# while using com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView library getting error inflating class exception

Tags: android

when i am using devsmartliberary from github in my project my app is going to crash i am unable to find out this error .i am new to android plz help me 
this is my main activity

```
package com.example.horizontal;

import com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String[] itemName = { "OverView", "History", "Budget", "Distribution",
            "Statistics" };
    Integer[] imageId = { R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2,
            R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.image5 };
    ListView lvList;
    GridView gvList;
    CustomerAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.horizontal);
        adapter = new CustomerAdapter(this, itemName, imageId);

        // gvList = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvList);
        // gvList.setAdapter(adapter);
        HorizontalListView hlv = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        //lvList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvList);
        hlv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my horizontal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ddd" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Exception are getting here

```
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.horizontal/com.example.horizontal.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at com.example.horizontal.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Analysis:

- `com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView` is the class path from
  your library project which you have used in xml
- If properly not refered, it cause Binary Xml Error

### Your Log says:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.horizontal/com.example.horizontal.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
03-24 15:19:36.692: E/AndroidRuntime(881):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
```

**It means:** *The library project is not properly referred in your project*

### Solution:

`Right click on your project` -> `Android` -> `in the right bottom` -> `click add and point to the library project of horizontal library, so that it is refered properly in your project`

---

### Edit

**horizontal.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"   
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#ddd" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have used this library in past ... it works ! ...... Try my edit and check once  !

Comment: i did same but facing with same problem

Comment: Tell me: when u right click on your project .... -> android ->  ..... can u see the refered project in red or blue ... if red its not properly refered

Comment: Hmm ... Ok  ... Then im not sure .... You can try one more thing .......... copy the `HorizontialListView.java` to your project to one of your package and give that name in your xml as for ex: `com.yourpackage.HorizontialListView` .... and of course remove the reference to library proj.... hope that works !

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and then i downloaded it's jar file and added that in my project..
You better use Recycler View for horizontal scrolling that is much much better than Horizontal listView and is one of the latest approaches. 
Secondly if you still want to use HSV then download this https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihfmr149z6liabb/devsmartlib.jar?dl=0  library and add it in your libraries folder and then right click and click Add as library and use HSV

Comment: explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting inflate error that means android is not able to find your HorizontalListView class, here is check list for getting out of this error:

1. As said by @Devrath you have to add library project to your project, check [ReferencingLibraryProject](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject).
2. If you still get this error then right click on project-> Properties -> select java builder path-> select Order and Export-> Make sure that "Android private libraries" must be checked.
3. If still your problem not solved then check and make sure you have given correct class reference in you layout file. For custom view you need to give full path to your class by  including package name `<packagename>.HorizontalListView`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue I've spent many infuriating hours figuring it out.  The only solution I could come up with was to change the devsmart package name then re-add it to my project then added it to the libraries. I believe this started because I changed my project package name so don't change your package name when working with this library I guess.

Ok first you need to add an 's' to the project library folder 'devsmartlibs' 
NOTE: That you only have to do this if it won't let you add the project because it's already been added as a project.

Then you import it as a project so: File -> Import -> Existing android code into workspace.  Then select the project location in browse and select finish.

After that right click on Your Project -> Properties -> Android -> Add (Bottom Right) -> now add the new library you've added to you project (devsmartlibs).

If this causes issues make sure that devsmartlibs has the same 'android-support-v4.jar' as your project because this can cause issues.

This worked for me I hope it helps.